# Getting npm packages to work with babel (babel-loader)

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm really new to webpack, babel, React and all this stuff. So I'm probably missing something really obvious. To get a jumpstart on my React project I'm using react-redux-bootstrap-webpack-starter. It all works well, but now my lack of understanding really shows with my latest problem.

**The problem:**

I'm trying to import jwtDecode from '[jwt-decode](https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode)' and it throws the following error:

```
./src/app/redux/modules/login.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jwt-decode/build/jwt-decode' in 
'/usr/src/app/src/app/redux/modules'
 @ ./src/app/redux/modules/login.js 12:17-55
 @ ./src/app/redux/modules/reducers.js
 @ ./src/app/redux/store/configureStore.dev.js
 @ ./src/app/redux/store/configureStore.js
 @ ./src/app/Root.js
 @ ./src/app/index.js
 @ multi react-hot-loader/patch webpack-hot-middleware/client 
./src/app/index.js
```

**What have I done:**

1. I've Docker-ized the frontend app, so I just added the jwt-decode package to package.json and rebuilt the image. The Docker build executes npm install.
2. I've tried to `import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode'` then I tried `import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode/build/jwt-decode`
3. I made sure I can reference other npm packages similarly installed. On a new docker instance I installed lodash, imported it in the same file and there was no problem.

My hypotheses:

- There's something about the particular jwt-decode package that makes it not work well with babel.
- To make it work I need either to modify the jwt-decode package or to configure webpack and the babel-loader differently. How?

Comment: Maybe wrong path? The path seems diferent from other packages

Answer (score 0):

Babel doesnt transpile anything for JWT-decode and I dont think webpack has any extra configuration for it either.

It looks like the places that you are trying to use jwt-decode, like: './src/app/redux/modules/login.js ', in your app cannot find the directory and so are failing.  Make sure that whatever module loader you're using is referencing the correct path to the jwt-decode directory.
Try loading it like this ( if you are using ES2015 via Babel transpilation):

```
import jwt_decode from "jwt_decode";
```

Comment: Thank you for your input on this. I'm afraid it didn't help. The message is still really similar. As I said I tried npm install lodash and import works as a charm. In the end I resorted to writing my own method, but I don't have a polyfill for atob() so there might be problems with older browers it seems.
    ERROR in ./src/app/redux/modules/login.js
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jwt_decode/build/jwt_decode' in '/usr/src/app/src/app/redux/modules'

Comment: Sorry I couldnt help.  
Maybe you could make sure `jwt-decode` is in your dependencies in package.json, as it would be expected to be.
Then remove your `node-modules/` directory.  Then rerun `npm install` to regenerate your dependencies & rebuild your `node-modules/` directory